# How to get the height constraint declared by Masonry for UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, masonry

For example, I declare some constraints through `Masonry` for a UIView:

```
[replyTextView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
  make.height.mas_equalTo(44);
  make.left.right.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView);
}];
```

How can I get the height constraint for the `replyTextView`?

I know I can use `replyTextView.constraints` to get all constraints, but I don't know how to tell them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
   // in public/private interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) MASConstraint *heightConstraint;

...

self.heightConstraint = [[replyTextView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
                            make.height.equalTo(@(44));
                            make.left.right.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView);
                        }] firstObject];//heightConstraint is first created MASConstraint
...

//heightConstraint is not composite MASConstraint, so we can access NSLayoutConstraint via KVC
NSLayoutConstraint *layoutConstraint = [heightConstraint valueForKey:@"layoutConstraint"];
CGFloat height = layoutConstraint.constant;//read
layoutConstraint.constant = height + 100;//modify
```

See also related discussion on the github page of Masonry: https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/206

Comment: It works, thanks! One more question, will my app be rejected in AppStore if I use this private key?

Comment: "layoutConstraint" is custom property of MASViewConstraint class (i.e. not private iOS API), your app will not be rejected

Comment: Just realized that this could be even easier:
`CGFloat height = [[heightConstraint valueForKey:@"layoutConstant"] floatValue];
[heightConstraint setOffset:(height+100)];`

Comment: Thanks. But I think `(NSLayoutConstraint *)constraint` will not response to `floatValue`?

Comment: In second case it uses `layoutConstant` instead of `layoutConstraint`, have a look again

Comment: Ah, that's great. May I ask where did you find these keys?

Comment: `layoutConstraint` - https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/blob/master/Masonry/MASViewConstraint.m#L42
`layoutConstant` - https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/blob/master/Masonry/MASViewConstraint.m#L46

Comment: Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned in the documentation:

```
   // in public/private interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) MASConstraint *heightConstraint;

...

// when making constraints
[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    self.heightConstraint =  make.height.mas_equalTo(44);
}];

...
// then later you can call
[self.heightConstraint uninstall];
```

Comment: have you tired accessing it?

Comment: I tried but failed. `MASConstraint` is just a wrapper abstract class which can set offset but cannot read constant.